# i can't have an attribute from an xpath with selenium

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

i'm working with selenium and i need to fill fields , my problem is i need to know the name of these fields from there xpath , i use selenium.getAttribute(myxpath ) but it doesn't work this is my java code :

```
  List<String> att= new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String ills:lls){
        att.add(selenium.getAttribute(ills));
    }
    logger.info("ma liste des attributs :"+att);
```

lls is the arrayList that contain all my ids .
and in my console i have 
ERROR: Element       form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:1:option:parametres:0:parametre:valeu not found

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is solution for above scenario

```
 String test= selenium.getAttribute("//input[@id='ID']@name");
 System.out.println(test);
```